# Determine return type based on input parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost, return-type

I'm trying to implement a generic configuration file parser and I'm wondering how to write a method in my class that is able to determine its return type, based on the type of an input parameter. Here's what I mean:

```
class Config
{
    ...
    template <typename T>
    T GetData (const std::string &key, const T &defaultValue) const;
    ...
}
```

In order to call the above method, I have to use something like this:

```
some_type data = Config::GetData<some_type>("some_key", defaultValue);
```

How can I get rid of the redundant  specification? I saw that boost::property_tree::ptree::get() is able to do this trick, but the implementation is rather complicated and I wasn't able to decipher this complex declaration:

```
template<class Type, class Translator>
typename boost::enable_if<detail::is_translator<Translator>, Type>::type
get(const path_type &path, Translator tr) const;
```

If possible, I would like to do this, without creating a dependency on boost in the code that will use my Config class.

PS: I'm a n00b when it comes to C++ templates :(

Comment: Is a templated class an option? You could write, for instance, `template <typename T> class Config {}` and instantiate it with `Config<some_type> instance;` and after that, use `instance` to work with and you don't need to specify things.

Comment: Rudolph's answer below is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `enable_if` in the code you’ve shown does something unrelated. In your case, you can just remove the explicit template specification, the compiler will infer it from the parameter:

```
some_type data = Config::GetData("some_key", defaultValue);
```

Even better, in C++11 you don’t even need to specify the variable type at declaration, it can be inferred as well:

```
auto data = Config::GetData("some_key", defaultValue);
```

… but note that C++ can only infer template arguments from parameters, not the return type. That is, the following does *not* work:

```
class Config {
    …
    template <typename T>
    static T GetData(const std::string &key) const;
    …
}
```

```
some_type data = Config::GetData("some_key");
```

Here, you’d either need to make the template argument explicit, or use a trick that returns a proxy class rather than the actual object, and defines an implicit conversion operator. Messy and most of the time unnecessary.

Comment: Oooooh... That is neat! I haven't tried that :D Thanks a million!