# How to handle an api which returns different data types for the same input data types?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, types, c++14

How to handle an api which returns different data types for the same input data types?

Looking at the below example, `apicall` should return a date or a string depending on the input attribute:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

???? apicall(string datatype, string attribute)
{
    // code
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string datatype = "Thomas"
    string attribute = "bithday"
    cout << apicall(datatype, attribute) << endl;

    string datatype = "Thomas"
    string attribute = "address"
    cout << apicall(datatype, attribute) << endl;
}
```

What could be in place of `????` (`apicall` return datatype) and how to handle these cases?

I am trying to understand these concepts as my experience to date has been with `duck typed` scripting languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080343/determine-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)

Comment: @underscore_d That’s based on the *type* of an input parameter, not the *value*.

Comment: right, so instead flag [Return type based on value of input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107012/return-type-based-on-value-of-input-parameter)

Comment: @underscore_d In that case the answer was “Don’t; it’s not worth it” because it’s easier to just return a complex number either way. That doesn’t apply here. In theory the questions are duplicates, but in practice the answers wouldn’t be.

Comment: @DanielH That was just one of the answers. One of the others suggested `boost::variant`, like the answer here, although it provided a more direct example of how to do it. So they look like dupes to me so far. But fine, it's up to others to decide because I've already made and retracted a flag.

Comment: Could something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tr92gaqk2MYpHHo1) work for your?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ideal solution is to use a [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which is a safe union type like.

This allows you to write the following:

```
using DateOrString = std::variant<DateType, std::string>;

DateOrString api_call(std::string, std::string) {
   // you can return both DateType and std::string
}

// ...
auto result = api_call("", "");
auto& str = std::get<std::string>(result);
```

Unfortunately `std::variant` is a *C++17* feature. However different compilers already support it.

As already has been suggested, [`boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) has a `variant` class and you can use it with any *C++ standard*.

---

As last option, you may implement a "variant-like" class which handles both a date and a string. Your function should return it.

[Here](http://ideone.com/gSBsEa) a demo how to quickly implement that kind of class.

Note that that class is safe because the type is checked at runtime.

As a *variant* object, your callee function should branch on the type, something like:

```
auto result = api_call(/*...*/);
if (result.is_string()) {
   // result is a string
   const auto& str = result.get_string();
} else {
   // result is a date
   const auto& date = result.get_date();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> ... returns different data types for the same input data types?

This is literally impossible. A function is defined with one (or zero) return types, and zero or more input parameter types.

The workarounds are:

1. Write a single function returning a variant type, such as [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) in C++17, or [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) if that's not available.
2. Write multiple functions with different return types (the caller just has to choose the right one)
3. Invert control, so that instead of returning a value, you pass an object capable of processing all the required types:

   ```
   struct APIHandler {
     virtual ~APIHandler() {}
     virtual void operator()(int) {}
     virtual void operator()(string) {}
   };
   void apicall(string name, string attr, APIHandler &h) {
     // dummy implementation
     if (attr == "address") {
       h("123 Woodford Road");
     } else if (attr == "birthday") {
       h(19830214);
     }
   }

   // implement your type-specific logic here
   struct MyHandler: APIHandler {
     void operator()(int i) override {
       cout << "got an int:" << i << '\n';
     }
     void operator()(string s) override {
       cout << "got a string:" << s << '\n';
     }
   };

   // and use it like:
   MyHandler mh;
   apicall("Thomas", "birthday", mh);
   apicall("Thomas", "address", mh);
   ```

Comment: This is a nice approach, similar to "visiting" a variant, but without the variant intermediary.  I would like APIHander be a template parameter so we could use generic lambda or other non-virtual implementations though.  But this gives the idea nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variant, but it's up to the caller site to check the results. Boost and std defines two variant types, i.e. [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Comment: In this case, a Boost (or `std`) variant is probably better, since Any can hold more than just dates and strings.

Comment: You should note that these classes have been adapted into the Standard Library as of C++17. Perhaps also link to documentation that readers could refer to, in either case.

Answer (score 2):

You want a `std::variant` in C++17 or a `boost::variant` or roll your own crude variant something like this:

```
constexpr std::size_t max() { return 0; }
template<class...Ts>
constexpr std::size_t max( std::size_t t0, Ts...ts ) {
    return (t0<max(ts...))?max(ts...):t0;
}
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct index_of_in;
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct index_of_in<T0, T0, Ts...>:std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};
template<class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
struct index_of_in<T0, T1, Ts...>:
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t,
        index_of_in<T0, Ts...>::value+1
    >
{};

struct variant_vtable {
  void(*dtor)(void*) = 0;
  void(*copy)(void*, void const*) = 0;
  void(*move)(void*, void*) = 0;
};
template<class T>
void populate_vtable( variant_vtable* vtable ) {
  vtable->dtor = [](void* ptr){ static_cast<T*>(ptr)->~T(); };
  vtable->copy = [](void* dest, void const* src){
    ::new(dest) T(*static_cast<T const*>(src));
  };
  vtable->move = [](void* dest, void* src){
    ::new(dest) T(std::move(*static_cast<T*>(src)));
  };
}
template<class T>
variant_vtable make_vtable() {
  variant_vtable r;
  populate_vtable<T>(&r);
  return r;
}
template<class T>
variant_vtable const* get_vtable() {
  static const variant_vtable table = make_vtable<T>();
  return &table;
}
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct my_variant {
  std::size_t index = -1;
  variant_vtable const* vtable = 0;
  static constexpr auto data_size = max(sizeof(T0),sizeof(Ts)...);
  static constexpr auto data_align = max(alignof(T0),alignof(Ts)...);
  template<class T>
  static constexpr std::size_t index_of() {
      return index_of_in<T, T0, Ts...>::value;
  }
  typename std::aligned_storage< data_size, data_align >::type data;
  template<class T>
  T* get() {
    if (index_of<T>() == index)
      return static_cast<T*>((void*)&data);
    else
      return nullptr;
  }
  template<class T>
  T const* get() const {
    return const_cast<my_variant*>(this)->get<T>();
  }
  template<class F, class R>
  using applicator = R(*)(F&&, my_variant*);
  template<class T, class F, class R>
  static applicator<F, R> get_applicator() {
    return [](F&& f, my_variant* ptr)->R {
      return std::forward<F>(f)( *ptr->get<T>() );
    };
  }
  template<class F, class R=typename std::result_of<F(T0&)>::type>
  R visit( F&& f ) & {
    if (index == (std::size_t)-1) throw std::invalid_argument("variant");
    static const applicator<F, R> table[] = {
      get_applicator<T0, F, R>(),
      get_applicator<Ts, F, R>()...
    };
    return table[index]( std::forward<F>(f), this );
  }
  template<class F,
    class R=typename std::result_of<F(T0 const&)>::type
  >
  R visit( F&& f ) const& {
    return const_cast<my_variant*>(this)->visit(
      [&f](auto const& v)->R
      {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(v);
      }
    );
  }
  template<class F,
    class R=typename std::result_of<F(T0&&)>::type
  >
  R visit( F&& f ) && {
    return visit( [&f](auto& v)->R {
      return std::forward<F>(f)(std::move(v));
    } );
  }
  explicit operator bool() const { return vtable; }
  template<class T, class...Args>
  void emplace( Args&&...args ) {
    clear();
    ::new( (void*)&data ) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    index = index_of<T>();
    vtable = get_vtable<T>();
  }
  void clear() {
    if (!vtable) return;
    vtable->dtor( &data );
    index = -1;
    vtable = nullptr;
  }
  ~my_variant() { clear(); }

  my_variant() {}
  void copy_from( my_variant const& o ) {
    if (this == &o) return;
    clear();
    if (!o.vtable) return;
    o.vtable->copy( &data, &o.data );
    vtable = o.vtable;
    index = o.index;
  }
  void move_from( my_variant&& o ) {
    if (this == &o) return;
    clear();
    if (!o.vtable) return;
    o.vtable->move( &data, &o.data );
    vtable = o.vtable;
    index = o.index;
  }
  my_variant( my_variant const& o ) {
    copy_from(o);
  }
  my_variant( my_variant && o ) {
    move_from(std::move(o));
  }
  my_variant& operator=(my_variant const& o) {
    copy_from(o);
    return *this;
  }
  my_variant& operator=(my_variant&& o) {
    move_from(std::move(o));
    return *this;
  }
  template<class T,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, my_variant>{}, int>::type =0
  >
  my_variant( T&& t ) {
    emplace<typename std::decay<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
};
```

then your code looks like:

```
variant<string, int> apicall(string datatype, string attribute)
{
  if (datatype > attribute) return string("hello world");
  return 7;
}

int main()
{
  string datatype = "Thomas"
  string attribute = "bithday"
  apicall(datatype, attribute).visit([](auto&&r){
    cout << r << endl;
  });
  string datatype = "Thomas"
  string attribute = "address"
  apicall(datatype, attribute).visit([](auto&& r){
    cout << r << endl;
  });
}
```

with whatever `visit` or `apply_visitor` free function or method your particular `variant` supports.

This gets much more annoying in C++11 as we don't have generic lambdas.